# Matrix representation of $ f$ with respect to basis

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Given

$$V = \{f: [-\pi,\pi] \to R;\ f(x) = a\,\sin(x) + b\,\cos(x)\ a,b \in \mathbb R\}$$

I have shown that it is a vector space with basis $$B = \{f_{1}=\sin(x),f_{2}=\cos(x)\} $$

Now the mapping $$D: V \to V, f(x) = f^{'}(x) $$ is given and I shall compute the matrix represntation of f with respect to basis B.

However, I am really not sure how to approach this. I know that every linear function $f$ can be represented as a matrix $A$ with respect to the standard bases as $$A=(f(e_{1},f(e_{2}),...f(e_{n}))$$.

So I would have solved it as following;

$$A_{B}=(f(f_{1}),f(f_{2})) = (f(\sin(x)),f(\cos(x))) = (\cos(x),-\sin(x))  $$

But I am not really sure - I think I have still problems to understand the concept behind it. Would be great if you could hep me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. The first column of the matrix is composed of the coordinates of $f(f_1)$ relatively to the base $B$.

$$f(f_1) = \cos(x) = 0\times f_1 + 1\times f_2$$

So the first column of $A_B$ shall be
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$.

Similarly, $f(f_2)=-\sin(x)=(-1)\times f_1+0\times f_2$, which means that the second column of $A_B$ is $\begin{bmatrix}
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$.

So
$$A_B=\begin{bmatrix}
0& -1\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let your linear transformation be called $D$ instead of $f$—it's a little confusing because you called the basis elements $f_1$ and $f_2$.  Since the domain of $D$ consists of functions, it's natural to name the input of $D$ by $f$.

So, $D\colon V\to V$ is the derivative operator: $Df = f'$.  To find its matrix representation in the basis $B$, you need to find scalars $a_{ij}$ such that
\begin{align*}
    Df_1 &= a_{11} f_1 + a_{12} f_2 \\
    Df_2 &= a_{21} f_1 + a_{22} f_2 \\
\end{align*}
Can you do that?

Comment: So the notation $Df = f^{'}$ is a little bit confusing for me why $Df$?

Comment: @Methamortix: You wrote “$D\colon V \to V$, $f(x) = f'(x)$.”  I think you meant that for every element $f(x)\in V$, $D(f)$ is the function $f'(x)$.  In linear algebra we get tired of writing parentheses all the time, especially in the case of linear transformations, which, after all, distribute over addition and scalar multiplication.  Also, the “$(x)$” notation in the naming of a function isn't necessary.  So we sweep all that under the rug and say $Df = f'$.

Comment: Ahhh ok now its perfectly clear thanks!

Comment: I just asked myself why f1 and f2 is actually a basis.  Of course it spans but when I try to show that they are lin indep. I stumble over the case when $a*0 + b*1 = 0$ for $\pi$ would lead to a being any number in $R$ and, thus, the condition for lin. Indep. does not hold?

Comment: @Methamortix: To check linear independence, suppose $a \sin(x) + b \cos(x) = 0$ for **all** $x\in[0,\pi]$.  Evaluate at $x=0$, and you get $a\cdot 0 + b \cdot 1= 0$, so $b=0$.  Evaluate at $x=\pi/2$, and you get $a\cdot 1 + b\cdot 0 = 0$, so $a=0$.

Comment: By reviewing this topic I just realised that your notation would result in the transposeed matrix of the Augustin, who posted above. Or am I mistaken to interpret the indices of your a's as matrix notation?